# write query correctly php pdo

Tags: php, mysql, sql, pdo

So I want to write the following query in `PHP` using `PHP` but I am wasting a ton of time trying to figure out something that should be simple.

Query in `SQL`

```
SELECT * 
FROM `table_name`
WHERE `column1` = 0560
```

Now it has to be exactly that way, the values **can't** have `' '`, or `" "`, or even back ticks around them. I tried it with those around the values and it just keeps failing even in `SQL` if its not exactly like the above.

Now I have tried the following, but none of which are successful and it's annoying me to no end

```
$a_query = "SELECT * FROM `".$table_name."` WHERE `".$column_name."` = `".$store_num."`";
$a_query = "SELECT * FROM `table_name` WHERE `column1` = `0560`";
```

I know I've tried a few other variations I just can't recall them right now. I've been at this for a while this evening.

Anyways I get this error every time

```
SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column '0560' in 'where clause'
```

Thanks for the help, I realize I'm probably missing something simple, my eyes are just fried

Comment: PS: http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepare.php

Comment: @zerkms I am using `PDO`, I had been told that if I wanted to pass the table name in `PDO` as a `variable` I had to write the query before I prepared it. Is this wrong?

Comment: normally you don't parameterize table names (it's bad, mkay), but if you do - you have to use white lists

Comment: @zerkms yes, its terrible, I have no choice in the matter, this db is a nightmare and I did not design it. Thank you for the "white lists" option I'll review it.

Comment: white list is just an array with all possible table names hardcoded. So before you put the table name (to the query) accepted from outside - you just check if it's in the allowed list, throw error otherwise.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

String literals should be enclosed in a single quotes `'`

Backticks `` ` `` are used to enclose identifiers (column name, table name, alias, etc)

Double quotes `"` behaviour depends on a correspondent [`sql_mode`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/server-sql-mode.html#sqlmode_ansi_quotes)

Comment: you're right, and I can query using backticks ` around the identifiers but I need the string to be without `' '` or `" "` and when I try and use backticks to accomplish this it isn't working. Is there another way? Ultimately it must be in variable form

Comment: @i_me_mine: I don't understand your question. Strings **SHOULD BE** enclosed in single quotes. Regardless of if you like that or not - it's an SQL syntax. "I need the string to be without" -- elaborate that

Comment: if my String is passed with `' '` or `" "` around it , it does not work. It needs to be read as 0560, not '0560' or "0560". So at the top where I have my query written from `SQL` *that* gives me results, when it is passed from `PHP` it must look identical.

Comment: @i_me_mine: so change your code so that it passed data in a correct form. If you want a string passed to be `0560` not `'0560'` - then just don't add quotes. I don't see how this question is related to sql syntax.

Comment: AHHHH! I literally wan't to punch something from my stupidity.... I am taking a break. I solved it. You were right, as I knew you were. I didn't notice that I had surrounded my variable in back ticks

Comment: I'm wondering why you're passing 0560 instead of 560. Is that an octal datatype or something?

Comment: @Sebas: actually in mysql `0560` equals to `560`